# regarding slashes using in urls pattern

Tags: django, django-views, url-rewriting

i am learning django for some days and i feel overwhelm by slashes using in url pattern like
**path("login"  , login  , name='login')**

sometimes we use slash in the starting , sometime in the end and sometime we use at both side like this **(/login, login/, /login/**).it is really very confusing

question = 1-what are these slashes and what does it do in my pattern
2 - when sould i use slash -  in starting , in end or at both side

i don't know exactly when to  use these slashes in url pattern so please guide me

Comment: I don't know anything about django but this is how things work normally. If an URL ends with a slash, you should be looking at the contents of a directory--preferably with an index file. If it doesn't end with a slash, you should be serving a file by that name.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what routes you want exactly. let's go with an example.
keep in mind that we have a Django with two apps called **main_app** and **api_app**. now we want to define routes to find out the difference.

> my_project/urls.app

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api_app.urls')),
    path('landing', include('main_app.urls')),
]
```

The first url `admin/` is defined as default for our Django admin panel.
It contains `/` at the end because we have some other routes come after that.
like `/admin/auth/user/`.
the second url is the same. keep in mind that we have some routes in our api_app.

> api_app/urls.py

```
from api_app.views import *
from django.urls import path
app_name = 'api_app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('info', info.as_view()),
]
```

So in this case, we defined a route by `api/info`. now if we remove the `/` from the end of `api/` that is defined in `my_project/urls.app`, our url will be `apiinfo`.(we can remove `/` from the end of `api/` and add it to begin of `info` to get same route)

and the last one `landing` is when we don't have any containing url.

for more details, you can read [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/)

Answer (score 0):

The slashes in Django URL patterns are used to define the structure of the URL. They act as separators between different parts of the URL.

The string "login" is the URL pattern or route that will be matched. In this case, it is the string "login", which means it will match the URL http://example.com/login.

Login is the view function or class-based view associated with the URL pattern. When the URL pattern is matched, Django will call this function or class-based view to handle the request and generate the response.

Using name='login' is an optional argument that gives a name to this URL pattern. It allows you to refer to this URL pattern by its name in other parts of your Django application, such as templates or other URLs. For example, you can use the name to generate the URL dynamically using the `{% url %}` template tag or the `reverse()` function.

You would use ('example1/') if you want to match a URL that ends with "example1/". It implies that the URL can have additional content or pages beyond "example1/". The trailing slash signifies that there may be more to explore within that URL.
For example Let's say you have a blog website. You can use the pattern ('example1/') to define the URL for the main blog page. So, when a user visits "https://www.example.com/example1/", Django will recognize that they are accessing the main blog page. This pattern suggests that there could be more pages or blog posts available under this URL, such as "https://www.example.com/example1/post1/", "https://www.example.com/example1/post2/", and so on. The trailing slash indicates that additional content or subpages can be found within that URL.

When you do ('/example2/'), it indicates an absolute URL path. This pattern is useful when you want to specify an exact URL path regardless of the current URL or directory structure. It overrides the current URL path and replaces it with the 'example2/' path. If you are for example on http://www.example.com/house/, it would replace the url path you are currently in "house" with "example2"

The pattern (/example3') represents a specific URL that stands alone and does not have any additional pages or content associated with it.
Let's say you have an "About" page for your website. You can define the URL pattern as ('/example3'). When a user visits "https://www.example.com/example3", Django will identify that they are accessing the "About" page. This pattern indicates that this URL represents a self-contained page without any child pages or additional content.

The pattern ('example4') does not have any slashes. It is used when you want to capture a specific string or parameter within a URL for further processing. This pattern allows you to handle dynamic values or customize the behavior based on the captured value.

Example: Suppose you have an e-commerce website with different categories. You can define the URL pattern as ('example4') and capture the category as a parameter. For instance, when a user visits "https://www.example.com/category/electronics/", Django will match this URL using the pattern ('example4') and capture the value "electronics". You can then use this captured value to display specific products or handle the request differently based on the category.